# How to handle cross thread error in C sharp windows application?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I'm having an application with a progress bar and a buttom.

When the button clicked the progress bar value will get increased, here is the source code,

```
private void Run()
        {               
                progressBar1.Maximum = 1000;
                progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
                progressBar1.Step = 1;

                for (int l_nIndex = 0; l_nIndex < 1000; l_nIndex++)
                {
                        progressBar1.Value++;
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
            }


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Run();
    }
```

so when i run the application, the progress bar value is getting increased, but when i try to move the window its not responding.

I can not run it in a normay thread way - it will throw Cross-Thread error.

so i changed the code like,

```
private void Run()
        {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Run));
                }
                else
                {
                    progressBar1.Maximum = 1000;
                    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
                    progressBar1.Step = 1;
                    for (int l_nIndex = 0; l_nIndex < 1000; l_nIndex++)
                    {
                            progressBar1.Value++;
                            Thread.Sleep(10);
                    }
                }
        }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart( Run));
              myThread.Start();
        }
```

Now i can able to move the winodow, but when i move the progress bar is stopped, and when i release the mouse button its resuming. So still the execution is in UI Thread. 
How to handle it in a better way.Please help me to do this .

Comment: See my answer here:

[Answer to "Cross Thread operation failed"][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489374/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-does-not-kill-winforms-application-and-it-sh/1489452#1489452

Comment: Everything here is wrong, i cannot do anything about it. Everything. Why you don't just use a Timer control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Invoke()` works by running the given delegate from the UI thread.  So if you use `Invoke()` to run **your entire method**, then your entire method runs from the UI thread.

Instead, you should be doing your actual **work** in the other thread, and just performing **UI updates** in the UI thread, by just `Invoke()`ing the little bits of code that perform the updates.

One easy way to do this is to use the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class built into the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180330) - in your case the code should look something like:

```
this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => progressBar1.Value++));
```