# Event, GUI and Threads

Tags: c#

I have parent form and child form. Parent form contains a dataGridView (list of accounts) and the child form allows a user to register an account.

The child form is launched on a separate thread.

When the account is registered, it's added to the SQL database and event is fired on the child form which the parent form subscribes to. The parent form then updates the dataGridView to add the new value from the database.

The problem is when trying to update the dataGridView in the parent form  upon the event being fired I get a cross thread error. Is this normal behaviour in this context?

Comment: any interaction with a ui control must be made from the thread that the control is created in. Assuming you're using win forms you'll need to use Control.BeginInvoke/Invoke method to interact with  a control created in another thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your handler you will have to do some work to bring the handler back on the UI thread... The "norm" is to using `InvokeRequired` and [`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) the following pattern:

```
private void OnChildFormSaysNewItemsHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Bring on the UI thread
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Action<object, EventArgs> handler = OnChildFormSaysNewItemsHandler;
        this.BeginInvoke(handler, sender, e);
        return;
    }

    // Do the normal work...
}
```

Comment: Would something like this be sufficient in the event handler? this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                fillData();
            });

Comment: After you're in the "do the normal work" section you are back on the UI thread, so you will be able to call `FillData()` without even worrying about invoke (which usually synchronously calls something on the UI thread).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's normal, the thread that fires the event is the child thread form. The code run in the mainform at this event is run in the child form thread. So it's normal.
I encourage you to never launch forms, controls in diferent thread. Stay in main thread. But you can use BackgroundWorker or anything else to do the internal process in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are not allowed to access UI elements from another thread than they were created on. You need to marshal the call across to the thread the parent form lives on (if you are using winforms then [InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) is your friend)

Answer (score 0):

Such behavior is expected - WinForms application model is not thread safe by design.
To interact with controls from non-UI thread use Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke() methods.

Example:

```
void RefreshData()
{
    // Refresh database here
}

void MyOtherThreadCallback()
{
   this.BeginInvoke(new Action(RefreshData()))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You parent form tries to update the grid view using the fired event's thread. That causes the cross thread error. To avoid that you have to update the control using the thread in which you created the control. This is usually done using code:

```
if(control.InvokeRequired)
{   
   control.Invoke(delegateToThisMethod)
}
```

and in the `delegateToThisMethod` you update grid view.

This question is answered in good depth in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489374/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-does-not-kill-winforms-application-and-it-sh/1489452#1489452)

Answer (score 0):

You don't list what version you are using, but check out the [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) on MSDN, it makes basic threading pretty easy.

You'll want to look at these events:

```
OnDoWork               Raises the DoWork event.
OnProgressChanged      Raises the ProgressChanged event.
OnRunWorkerCompleted   Raises the RunWorkerCompleted event.
```

What happens in the DoWork method is on a separate thread (and anything it calls), but both the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted methods that you create run on the UI thread and thus can update UI elements.